# Jest mock for redis-sessions functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, jestjs, mocking

I want to mock the redis-session function.

```
static async createSession(userData: string, userId: Uuid, ipAddress: string = 'NA'): Promise<string> {
try {
  const rs = this.getRedisConnection();
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject): void => {
    rs.create(
      {
        app: Configs.rsSessionApp,
        id: userId,
        ip: ipAddress,
        ttl: Configs.rsDefaultTtl,
        d: {
          data: userData,
        },
      },
      (err: object, resp: { token: string }): void => {
        if (resp !== undefined && resp.token.length > 0) {
          return resolve(resp.token);
        }

        if (err != null) {
          reject(err);
        }
      },
    );
  });
} catch (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error.message);
}
```

}

I want to make this line execute (err: object, resp: { token: string }): void => {}
How to achieve or resolve this using jest unit test?.
Another unit test to throw the error.

Comment: What's the return value of `this.getRedisConnection()` ?

Comment: It returns a new redis-session with given port number and url.
`return new redisSession({
      host: Configs.redisConnectionInfo.host,
      port: Configs.redisConnectionInfo.port,
      namespace: Configs.rsapp});`

Answer (score 0):

`try...catch...` cannot catch the exception of asynchronous code, you can remove it.

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to mock `RedisSession.getRedisConnection()` method and return a mocked redis connection. Then, mock the implementation of `rs.create()` method, you can get the anonymous callback function in your test case.

At last, call the anonymous callback function manually with mocked arguments.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import RedisSessions from 'redis-sessions';

interface Uuid {}

export class RedisSession {
  static async createSession(userData: string, userId: Uuid, ipAddress: string = 'NA'): Promise<string> {
    const rs = this.getRedisConnection();
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject): void => {
      rs.create(
        {
          app: 'test',
          id: userId,
          ip: ipAddress,
          ttl: 3600,
          d: {
            data: userData,
          },
        },
        (err: object, resp: { token: string }): void => {
          if (resp !== undefined && resp.token.length > 0) {
            return resolve(resp.token);
          }

          if (err != null) {
            reject(err);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }

  static getRedisConnection() {
    return new RedisSessions({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: '6379', namespace: 'rs' });
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { RedisSession } from './';

describe('67220364', () => {
  it('should create redis connection', async () => {
    const mRs = {
      create: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((option, callback) => {
        callback(null, { token: '123' });
      }),
    };
    const getRedisConnectionSpy = jest.spyOn(RedisSession, 'getRedisConnection').mockReturnValueOnce(mRs);
    const actual = await RedisSession.createSession('teresa teng', '1');
    expect(actual).toEqual('123');
    expect(getRedisConnectionSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mRs.create).toBeCalledWith(
      {
        app: 'test',
        id: '1',
        ip: 'NA',
        ttl: 3600,
        d: {
          data: 'teresa teng',
        },
      },
      expect.any(Function)
    );
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67220364/index.test.ts (8.636 s)
  67220364
    ✓ should create redis connection (5 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      70 |    57.14 |      75 |      70 |                   
 index.ts |      70 |    57.14 |      75 |      70 | 24-33             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.941 s
```